# Improve confidence interval by averaging

Tags: probability, statistics

**Data** A GPS sensor is specified with "precision of 10m 2sigma", which I understand as "95% of the measures are within a 20m diameter sphere centred on the actual position". There is no context information like the number of samples used to measure this value.

**Question** I want to bring down the confidence interval by averaging the values, and I am looking for a relationship between number of values averaged VS confidence interval, assuming a Gaussian distribution.

I could not find anything online , though this is a very important question for engineering applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding independant(!) Gausian distributions also adds variances. Therefore tha average of $n$ independant measuremens has standard deviation divided by $\sqrt n$. It is doubtful however if the independancy asusmption is justified for measurements taken in relatively rapid succession (i.e. with almost the same satellite positions), i.e. when we are not sure whethre the error is due to random noise or more or less systematic errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I understand is: the initial variance is $\sigma_i=\frac{10}{2\times 1.96}=2.55m$, so for 10 values averaged the new variance is $\sigma_n=\frac{2.55}{\sqrt{10}}=0.806m$ which yields a 2sigma confidence interval of $I=\pm 0.806\times 1.96=\pm 1.58m$ (detailed steps). Is that correct if I consider no uncompensated systematic errors?

Comment: Why did you divide by $2$ when calculating $\sigma_i$? (You'd get the wrong result for "averaging" a single measurement). Also, since you start with $95\%$ and presumably want the result as $95\%$ interval again, there is no need to divide by $1.96$ and multiplying again. You can in fact simply divide the $10\,\mathrm m$ by $\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: Yes that is why I said "detailed steps", it can be further factorised. I divided by 2 to get a "$\pm$" notation rather than an interval length. Should I take it that it is correct (before I accept your answer)? If so, what would you reckon to be the next step towards improving that estimate (or is that an accurate model)?